# How to take inputs using "range based for loop"

Tags: loops, for-loop, c++11, cin, range-based-loop

The loop containing "cin" doesn't change the values. What is happening inside the loop? And how can I use this(range based loop) to take inputs?

INPUT:-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5};

    //with outputs/cout it work properly
    for(auto x:arr)
    {
        cout<<x<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;


    //Now suppose, I want to change them
    for(auto x:arr)
    {
        cin>>x;
    }

    //now again printing
    for(auto x:arr)
    {
        cout<<x<<" ";
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:-

```
1 2 3 4 5
9 8 7 6 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty simple!! we just have to use ampersand operator with the created variable.

INPUT:-

```
int main()
{
    int arr[4];

    //INPUT VALUES
    for(auto &x:arr)
    {
        cin>>x;
    }

    //PRINTING VALUES
    for(auto x:arr)
    {
        cout<<x<<" ";
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:-

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```